# Fujitsu Amilo D7830 Laptop frequently won't boot

Tags: boot, laptop

I have a 6 year old Fujitsu-Siemens Amilo D7830 which has been sitting in my "spares" pile for a while, and which I am trying to re-commission.

On attempting to power it up (on AC power), one of three things will happen.

- It will appear to try to boot, but switch off after a second or so.
- Or the fans spin up, and the lights come on, but nothing else, and it sits there with the fans going full speed but no other signs of life.
- Or it will boot fine.

Usually it will eventually boot after several attempts, but it takes a lot more attempts than it did when I first retired it.

The battery has long since expired, but leaving it in or removing it makes no discernible difference.

I've read rumors of a Power Management Chip in these models that can fail and/or need a reset, but can't find any further information on this or how to identify it/reset it.

Does anyone know if this indeed the problem, and if so how to reset it?

Comment: Is the cmos battery ok? Most laptops can do a hard reset by removing AC and main battery, hold the power button down for 30 seconds. Enter the bios and set the date and time if needed. Reseat the memory modules a few times.

Comment: The CMOS batter is, now, as flat as a pancake - but the machine has been sitting in a cupboard with no main battery for the best part of two years, and didn't show any of the normal symptoms of a flat CMOS battery when the above problem first started occurring. I thought that wouldn't prevent it from booting anyway, just cause it to lose its settings each time power was lost?